# Why does query parameter type affects mysql index choice?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select a, b, c from sometable where cateId = ? /**1**/
```

We can also do this:

```
select a, b, c from sometable where cateId = "1"
```

as MySQL will cast it. Interestingly I observed different performance characteristics on these two queries. Why this is the case?

I omitted quite some details regarding table structure and index details, but in general is it possible for such scenario to really occur, and why?

adding the details I mentioned. if it helps.

```
    select
        memberId,
        prodId,
        prodName,
        sum(count) as total
    from
        SOMETABLE
    where
        statDate >= ?
        and statDate<= ?
        and catId = ?
        and name <> 'OTHERS'
    group by
        memberId, prodName
    order by
        total desc
    limit 5

    --IDX catId, prodName
    --IDX catId, statDate
    --IDX memberId, statDate
    --IDX catId, statDate, prodName, prodId, count
```

Comment: "Is it possible?" Well, obviously yes, you've come across one such scenario yourself. "Why?" Now that's where the omitted details may be important for the answer.

Comment: `VARCHAR` = number -- won't use index.  `INT` = string -- will convert the string, then use index (is appropriate).  `INT` = number and `VARCHAR` = string -- no conversion, no problem using index.

Answer (score 0):

Query processing takes the given SQL, applies a set of rules and heuristics and comes up with an execution plan. This states which indexes are used and how. The outcome is dependent on the input and how the rules have been written.

Given a slightly different start point a different end point may result. It's somewhat like dropping a ball in a landscape of river vallies. Drop it once and it will roll into a river. Drop it in a slightly different place and chances are it will roll down into the same river. Occasionally, if you're near a ridge, you drop the ball in a slightly different place and it rolls into the next river instead.

Comment: I understand the metaphor, can we discuss one such scenario specifically regarding the type parameter implicit cast

Comment: I'm happy to listen as you talk. My knowledge of MySQL is shallow, however. You're likely to get a better result by posting the actual execution plan with table definitions and statistics, perhaps as a new question referencing this one.

Comment: Best of all MySQL is open source. You can find out *exactly* what's happening, if you have the patience to look.